# How can I groupby and aggregate pandas dataframe with many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a pandas dataframe with 168 columns. First three columns contain name of the country, latitude and longtitude. Rest of the columns contain numerical data. Each row represents a country but for some countries there are multiple rows. I need to aggregate those rows by summing. I can aggregate first three columns with following code:

```
df = df.groupby('Country', as_index=False).agg({'Lat':'first','Long':'first'})
```

However, I couldn't find a way to include in that code remaining 165 columns without explicitly writing all the column names. In addition, column names represent dates and are named like `5/27/20`,`5/28/20`,`5/29/20`, etc. So I need to keep the column names.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can generate the dictionary from the column names:

```
df = df.groupby('Country', as_index=False).agg({c: 'first' for c in df.columns})
```

Comment: I generated a dictionary as @Jonas suggested:
`df1 = df.groupby(['Country/Region'], as_index=False).agg({c: np.sum for c in df.columns[4:]})`
However it didn't include _Lat_ and _Long_ columns. I tried to add `'Lat':'first', 'Long':'first'` to the above code in different ways but it gave syntax error.
As a workaround I generated a second dataframe with 'Country','Lat' and 'Long': columns
`df2 = df.groupby(['Country/Region'], as_index=False).agg({'Lat':'first','Long':'first'})`
Then I merged _df1_ and _df2_:
`df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='Country', right_on='Country')` -Thanks